# Java logback logging send email conditionally

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback

I am using the latest version of spring boot.

I have the below code in various classes.

```
LOGGER.info(" send email : " +  EMAIL); // EMAIL="send_email"
```

I need to send emails whenever a log is generated with the keyword **"send_email"**
I have below conditions to send an email

1. send email only when there are 100 log messages i.e 1 email for 100 log messages
   2)OR send an email once in 1 hour if there are not 100 messages.

How can I achieve this using Spring boot?

Comment: Make your own (SLF4J-compatible) logger?

Comment: any hint/link for that?

Comment: http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#slf4j_compatible

Comment: This really isn't what loggers are for. It sounds like you want a proper event queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot uses logback as default. SLF4J is just a facade for several logging frameworks.

If you are using logback, you can customize the SMTPAppender to pass evaluator parameter to decide if the log message should be processed by SMTPAppender or not.

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="ERROR_MAILER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <evaluator class="app.Evaluator"> </evaluator>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>


    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR_MAILER"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

gt.app.Evaluator

```
package app;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.EventEvaluatorBase;

public class Evaluator extends EventEvaluatorBase<ILoggingEvent> {
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(ILoggingEvent event) throws NullPointerException {
        return event.getMessage().contains("THE_KEYWORD_HERE");
    }
}
```

Reference: Source code of ch.qos.logback.core.net.SMTPAppenderBase

See also: ch.qos.logback.core.net.SMTPAppenderBase#checkEntryConditions

Comment: able to generate   emails  now

Comment: How do i send 1 email per 2 messages lets say ..i tried  this but i keep getting 2 emails `<cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker"> 
        <bufferSize>2</bufferSize>
    </cyclicBufferTracker>`

Comment: Just look at the source code of SMTPAppender and you will find some hint